How do I get a domain name back that is owned by a publisher without spending $200?
I am developing a website for my mother in law, she wrote a book and contracted with the publisher to open a website with them using her first and last name as her domain name. The contract has passed and the website is not in service, just a lander site, but when I talk to the gatekeepers at the publishing house they won't give me any information. If they aren't using the domain, how can I get it from them without paying a large fee for a broker for it?

So what does the contract say? Looks like this is a purely legal question that should be posted to another community.

Unless you can get the Auth Code/EPP Code there is no cheap way of doing it - so I would get the authorized person to request/demand this from them.  (Once you have this code, you should be able to just shift the domain to a provider of your choice).   If you are patient, you may be able to go to a "domain backorder" service and purchase the domain through them if you are willing to wait until its expired and take the risk that someone else gets it first.    You certainly should not need to pay brokers fees though - a broker can't do anything you cant.

You may also want to advise either the domain name, or the end of the domain name as different tld's have different requirements/processes (although they are generally similar).   If you provide the full domain name we may be able to provide additional information on the registry process and contact process - but this might very,very marginally increase the risk of the domain name being gazumped if you do wait for it to expire.
